# Why does the addition of two shorts return an int?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I read a c++ tutorial that says arithmetic operators return the smallest data type possible (i.e. if 2 ints are added the return type will be int, if a float and a double are added the return type will be double). However, it also said that arithmetic operations on shorts return ints. Considering that shorts take up less memory than ints, why does that happen? Was the tutorial mistaken? The tutorial was for c++11, so maybe that has been deprecated in c++14? Thanks!

Comment: "*I read a c++ tutorial that says arithmetic operators return the smallest data type possible*" Is that available online so we can see the context? That seems to be the opposite of the correct answer. For example `1 + 2.0;` does not return an `int`.

Comment: 2.0 is a double...

Comment: Don't blame the language, blame _your_ architecture. (Integer) Arithmetic processing in c.p.u.s require operands to be `int`s and return `int`s. So yeah `short + short` gives an `int`, `short + int` also gives `int`. This is because _your_ c.p.u. requires them to be `int`s to perform any arithmetic operation and as a result they are cast to `int`s, the operation is performed and the result is returned as `int`.

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar, The language explicitly says this as a rule. The rule was likely based on hardware, but really, the language could have just as easily defined it differently.

Comment: @chris I have not yet seen any architecture that does not do this. C++ is a language that does not shy away from hardware, and has been standardized based on the most widespread currently in-use hardware. So, I don't see a point in defining it differently, which also has another advantage: The programmer gets a peek a what happens underneath. The problem is with all these _misinterpreted_ tutorials that do not state everything. This page is what should be read: [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/faq)

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar, That doesn't contradict anything I said. It's up to the language to make the decision of more performant vs. perhaps more intuitive there.

Comment: @chris Not trying to contradict you. Just stating a point. :)

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar: this is not strictly true. x86 supports 16-bit or 8-bit addition directly, without extending to ints. Also on hardware which supports only int arithmetic the standard still could specify `short+short == short`, [which is arguably a better design choice](http://stannum.co.il/blog/5/sized-integer-types-and-signedness).

Comment: @ybungalobill +1 for teaching me a new thing today!

Answer (score 2):

> Considering that shorts take up less memory than ints, why does that happen?

That's because the standard says so.

> Was the tutorial mistaken?

No.

---

From the C++11 Standard (note the *usual arithmetic conversion* bit):

> **5 Expressions**
>
> ...
>
> 9 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> — Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.

*Integral promtions* is defined in the standard as:

> **4.5 Integral promotions**
>
> 1 A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

As per above a `short` is promoted to an `int` before some of the binary operators are applied to the operands.

The section about operators `+` and `-` specifically mentions that usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands:

> **5.7 Additive operators**
>
> 1 The additive operators `+` and `-` group left-to-right. The usual arithmetic conversions are performed for operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.

Answer (score 1):

The type `int` is the "natural size" for the target system. Integer types that are smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` in arithmetic expressions so that the processor can be most efficient. That may be less of a concern these days, but it's still part of the C and C++ languages.