# g++ warning: conversion to uint16_t from int may alter its value

Tags: c++, g++

At the advice of a high rep SO user, I've recently started compiling with the `-Wconversion` flag on my codebase.  This has generated quite a few warnings, some which are legitimate (needlessly adding `signed` and `unsigned` types, for instance), but also some head scratchers, demonstrated below:

```
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
  uint16_t a = 4;
  uint16_t b = 5;

  b += a;

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile with `g++ -Wconversion -std=c++11 -O0 myFile.cpp`, I get

```
warning: conversion to 'uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
    b += a;
      ^
```

I've perused some similar questions on SO (dealing with `|` and `<<` operators), taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators), and have read the Numeric Promotions and Numeric Conversions sections [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).  My understanding is, in order to do the math, `a` and `b` are promoted to `int` (since that's the first type that can fit the entire `uint16_t` value range), math is performed, the result is written back... except the result of the math is an `int`, and writing that back to `uint16_t` generates the warning.  The consensus of the other questions was basically to cast away the warning, and the only way I've figured out how to do that is `b = (uint16_t)(b + a);` (or the equivalent `b = static_cast<uint16_t>(b + a);`).

Don't want this question to get too broad, but assuming my understanding of integer promotions is correct...

1. What's the best way to handle this moving forward?  Should I avoid performing math on types narrower than `int`?  It seems quite odd to me that I have to cast an arithmetic result which is the same type as all the operands (guess I would expect the compiler to recognize that and suppress the warning).  Historically, I've liked to use no more bits than I need, and just let the compiler handle the promotions/conversions/padding as necessary.
2. Anyone use `-Wconversion` flag frequently?  Just after a couple of days of using it myself, I'm starting to think its best use case is to turn it on, look at what it complains about, fix the legitimate complaints, then turn it back off.  Or perhaps my definition of "legitimate complaint" needs readjusting.  Replacing all of my `+=` operators with spelled out casts seems like a nuisance more than anything.

I'm tempted to tag this as `c` as well, since an equivalent `c` code compiled with `gcc -Wconversion -std=c11 -O0 myFile.c` produces the exact same warning.  But as is, I'm using `g++` version 5.3.1 on an x86_64 Fedora 23 box.  Please point me to the dupe if I've missed it; if the only answer/advice here is to cast away the warning, then this is a dupe.

Comment: It's not quite a dup, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39061103/1270789) confirms your suspicions. How to deal with `-Wconversion` warnings, though, is unanswered, but worth answering here. (And [C# is even more confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343624/1270789)).

Comment: clang handles `-Wconversion` differently, it doesn't warn for this case. I use this switch turned on all the time (I don't turn off, like you say in 2.), and I always fix the issues. But I rarely use shorter types for arithmetics. There's simply no reason for using them.

Comment: "At the advice of a high rep SO user"  - well, my advice would be to not use that flag because it gives too many false positives!  Frankly, I consider the case in your question to be a compiler bug.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo `g++` 5.3.1 .. sorry put that all the way at the bottom. I don't have quick access to clang right now or I would've tried it there too. Interesting that it doesn't warn for this, geza, thanks for the info.

Comment: "Just after a couple of days of using it myself, I'm starting to think its best use case is to turn it on, look at what it complains about, fix the legitimate complaints, then turn it back off." Pretty much what I do. I often have a "paranoid" target in the makefile that has pretty much everything turned on. If I was the high-rep SO user, I apologize. All of the stuff I check before posting as an answer gets the paranoid treatment and I've copied the paranoid warning flags into comments in the past.

Comment: @user4581301 Paranoid target sounds like a good idea. But nah, it wasn't you. No harm in naming names, right? It was [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin). It was a comment posted about using the `-Wconversion` flag on some question I saw last week, so I thought I'd give it a go.

Answer (score 4):

I think this can be considered a shortcoming of gcc.

As this code doesn't generate any warning:

```
int a = ..., b = ...;

a += b;
```

This code should not generate either, because semantically they are the same (two same-type numbers are added, and the result is put into a same-type variable):

```
short a = ..., b = ...;

a += b;
```

But GCC generates a warning, because as you say, the `short`'s gets promoted to `int`'s. But the `short` version isn't more dangerous as the `int` one, in the sense that if the addition overflows, then the behavior is implementation-defined for the `short` case, and undefined for the `int` case (or if unsigned numbers are used, then truncation can happen in both cases).

Clang handles this case more intelligently, and doesn't warn for this case. I think it's because it actually tracks the possible bit-width (or maybe range?) of the result. So, for example, this warns:

```
int a = ...;
short b = a;
```

But this doesn't (but GCC warns for this):

```
int a = ...;
short b = a&0xf; // there is a conversion here, but clang knows that only 4 bits are used, so it doesn't warn
```

So, until GCC will have a more intelligent `-Wconversion`, your options are:

1. don't use `-Wconversion`
2. fix all the warnings it prints
3. use clang instead (maybe for GCC: turn off this warning; and for clang: turn it on)

But don't hold your breath until it's fixed, there is a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40752) about this, opened in 2009.

A note:

> Historically, I've liked to use no more bits than I need, and just let the compiler handle the promotions/conversions/padding as necessary.

If you use shorter types for storage, it's fine. But usually, there's no reason to use shorter types than `int` for arithmetic. It gives no speedup (even, it can be slower, because of the unnecessary maskings).

Answer (score 4):

> What's the best way to handle this moving forward?

```
-Wno-conversion
```

Or just leave it unspecified. This is just an opinion, though.

In my experience, the need for narrow integer arithmetic tends to be quite rare, so you could still keep it on for the project, and disable for the few cases where this useless warning occurs. However, this probably depends highly on the type of your project, so your experience may vary.

> Should I avoid performing math on types narrower than int?

Usually yes; unless you have a specific reason to use them. *"I don't need the extra bits"* isn't a specific enough reason in my opinion. Arithmetic operands are promoted to `int` anyway and it's usually faster and less error prone to use `int`.

> Just after a couple of days of using it myself, I'm starting to think its best use case is to turn it on, look at what it complains about, fix the legitimate complaints, then turn it back off.

This is quite often a useful approach to warning flags that are included in neither `-Wall` nor `-Wextra` such as the ones with `-Wsuggest-` prefix. There is a reason why they aren't included in "all warnings".