# C++ Adding two uint16_t does not compile in clang

Tags: c++, clang

Why can't the following code be compiled in clang?

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  uint16_t one{1};
  uint16_t two{one + one};
  return 0;
}
```

See [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YP7bcs4n1). Error message:

```
<source>:4:16: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'uint16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    4 |   uint16_t two{one + one};
      |                ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:4:16: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
    4 |   uint16_t two{one + one};
      |                ^~~~~~~~~
      |                static_cast<uint16_t>( )
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: braced init => no narrowing allowed. ```+``` is promoting args and result to int and brace init does not allow to implicitly cast. Do just as the compiler diagnosis says: explicitely cast the result to uint16_t. Aternatively, you can use the assign init syntax (```=```)

Comment: @Oersted But everything is of the same type `uin16_t`, the sum `one+one` should also be of type `uint16_t`. I don't understand why type casts are necessary. Furthermore why does gcc compile with warning and clang does not compile?

Comment: Why is + promoting the args? I thought addition of same POD types keeps that type as result type.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion <- "In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments"

Comment: @teapot418 Thank you. This explains the error. But then why does gcc not fail with error? Braced initialization for numbers should only allow arguments of same type I think.

Comment: There is a "may be" in there. Perhaps both behaviors are legal?

Comment: please include the error message in the question.

Comment: [Why does the addition of two shorts return an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39060852/995714), [Addition of two chars produces int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4814668/995714)

Comment: as far as I remember narrowing as error is not mandatory, compilers are free to do what they want. If you want consistent behavior accross compiler, there are some compilation options to force it I think (-Werror=narrowing)

Comment: `inline auto add(uint16_t a, uint16_t b) -> uint16_t { return static_cast<uint16_t>(a + b); }` and then you can `uint16_t two{add(one, one)};` without compiler complaint. *the sum one+one should also be of type uint16_t.*  C++ inherited the promotion behavior from C.  I imagine most C++ developers would agree with you (myself included), but that ship has sailed.

Comment: I've got it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15805532/21691539. gcc emits a warning. It's enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `one + one` is of type `int` because the default arithmetic conversions promote operands smaller than `int` to `int` before performing the addition.

Reference:
[Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371868/why-must-a-short-be-converted-to-an-int-before-arithmetic-operations-in-c-and-c)

Thus, you need to cast `int` to `uint16_t` manually.

```
uint16_t two = static_cast<uint16_t>(one + one);
```

Comment: the cast is required only with the brace-init syntax I think. With =, at most you'll get a conversion warning

Comment: Yes, you are right. By using copy assignment operator `uint16_t two = (one + one);`, there is no warning or error. I think in C++, when using copy initialization with curly braces, compiler is stricter than using copy assignment operator.

Comment: indeed it is: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization. Besides regarding the compilers behavior its quite unclear: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783. I couldn't find the wording in standard that would authorize a compiler to accept narrowing (on the other hand it is written that narrowing gives a *ill-formed* program)